# NUnit - Is it possible to count total test, total time, total passed test?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

Can we count total test, total time, total passed test in NUnit ?

Currently having, In which test got identify with Pass/Fail. I am looking for if is there any method, which gives count;

```
            if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status.ToString() == "Failed")
            {
                Log.Info("TestContext.Message = " + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message);
                Log.Info("TestContext.StackTrace = " + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace);
            }
            else if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status.ToString() == "Passed")
            {
                Log.Info("TestContext.Status = " + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info("Undefined TestContext.Status = " + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

As you may have guessed, `TestContext` is really only useful while tests are running. Trying to get the final results while tests are still running is kind of like trying to get your final hotel bill while you are still using the room. The answer you get is tentative and subject to change, for example, if you eat breakfast, take something from the minibar, watch a movie, etc.

For that reason, it's best to wait till after the tests are over to look at the results. For an individual test case, that would be in the `[TearDown]` method. For a fixture or SetUpFixture, in the `[OneTimeTearDown]` method. Even so, if those methods happen to throw an exception, all bets are off!

For the total run, I would use an engine extension rather than putting the code in my tests. You would write a TestListener extension. In it, you would only take action when the entire test run is complete. Then the entire outcome of the test, including all the counts would be available. This is the "correct" approach, but it's also a bit more work than what you are doing. See docs for details.

Another approach is to write a program that processes the test result XML file and gets the info there. This has the advantage of being a separate, straightforward program and not requiring you to know how to write extensions.

Finally, as a workaround, you can use code similar to what you have. **However**, it may not work in all future releases, because it uses knowledge of internal structures...

1. Create an assembly-level `SetUpFixture` with a `OneTimeTearDown` method. To be assembly-level, it must be outside of any of your namespaces.
2. In the OneTimeTearDown, access `NUnit.Framework.Internal.TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentResult`. This field is a `TestResult` and contains everything there is to know about the result of the assembly, including counts of tests that passed, failed etc.
3. Whatever else you do, do not try to do **anything** that changes the TestResult. Odds are you'll break something if you do that. :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your detail guidance. It seems difficult from your explanation. But I will look in to it.

Comment: For the easiest approach, I'd suggest using the third option, i.e. the workaround. Even though it's not guaranteed to keep working across new versions of NUnit, you can deal with that when it happens.